# Regular expression to find even/odd number

Tags: python

I used codes below to find out even numbers from a string and returned nothing.

could anyone tell me what I missed? Thank you very much.

```
import re

str2 = "adbv345hj43hvb42"

even_number = re.findall('/^[0-9]*[02468]$/', str2 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In python you should not wrap expression with slashes (`'/^[0-9]*[02468]$/'` -> `'^[0-9]*[02468]$'`)
2. `$` and `^` are used to match the beginning and the end of string (or line in MULTILINE regex). But your example doesn't look you need to (`'^[0-9]*[02468]$''` -> `'[0-9]*[02468]'`)
3. After that you need to stop matching only prefixes (`'[0-9]*[02468]'` -> `r'[0-9]*[02468](?![0-9])'`)
4. That's it :)
   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I like the way you solve the problem. meanwhile could you tell me the meaning of (?![0-9]) ?  can't be followed by number, right?

Comment: Yes, it's a [negative lookahead assertion](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions)

Answer (score 2):

Your re matches:

1. Start of string
2. 0 or more digits 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9
3. One even number
4. End of string

That does not match your string, you should drop the begin of string `^` and end of string `$` markers

To find an even number, just match any number of digits that ends with an even number '/[0-9]*02468/'

Comment: But that will match a *digits*, not a *numbers*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want to extract from the string, but in order to match single even numbers use such syntax: `[02468]` (find one of the present in the list).